# How to write a iText pdf file in a remote location

Tags: java, server

In my web application, want generate PDF files, used iText to generate PDF. I want write those files on server.

I used the below code to write PDF in my local machine

```
PdfWriter writer =  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Reports\testFile.pdf"));
```

Instead of this i want create a pdf in a remote location

```
http://103.xx4.xx4.2/Reports/testFile.pdf
```

Please guide me how to do this.
Good leads will be appreciatable.

Comment: Create a mapped network drive to your remote location and use it as the file path in constructor of `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Could you give me an example.

Comment: Simply search the Internet for "how to map windows network drive".

Comment: I mapped the network, the issue is in making a connection with that network.

Comment: You will have to use some Upload mechanism like [FTP Upload](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/ftp/java-ftp-file-upload-tutorial-and-example) or such.

Comment: I uploaded file by using shared network, but now it's not able download. any idea